# Count rows after specific one

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

A table `users` has three columns: `id, name, pass`.

Another table `logins` has `user_id` column, an `isright` boolean (tinyint) column which says whether the login was successful or not and a `date` column.

I need a simple `left join` to get the user's name and his password **(1)**, the last login datetime (successful or not) **(2)** and the count of the logins for the specific user since his last successful login **(3)**.

(1) and (2) I can achieve using

```
SELECT name, pass, MAX(date)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN logins ON logins.id = users.id
-- here either "GROUP BY users.id" or "WHERE users.id = 1234"
```

But (3) seems to be harder. I googled it and found many similar question but none of them was asking on exactly how to count rows after specific condition is true. (It's even more complicated - count the logins for *that* user, not everyone)

I don't even know how to do it in a separate query (I'd prefer having one query for the 3 things and I suppose I'd have to use a subquery, although I prefer joins).

SQL fiddle with the tables and some data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a932b

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried getting the date/time of the last succesfull login using a subquery and then only counting the ones that have a date after that date/time ? if you can give me a description of both your tables I might be able to help out more

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH the desired result.

Comment: @JeremyC. - here is a sqlfiddle with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a932b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward way is to have two derived tables: One to get the last login date per user, the other to get the last successful login date per user. Then select from users, outer join the two derived tables and look whether the last login was successful and count the (failed) logins after the last successful login. (With another DBMS you would rather use analytic functions that MySQL lacks.)

```
select 
  users.name, 
  users.pass, 
  (
    select max(isright)
    from logins 
    where user_id = students.id and date = last_login.date
  ) as last_login_successful,
  (
    select count(*)
    from logins
    where user_id = students.id and date > last_successful_login.date
  ) as last_logins_failed
from users
left outer join
(
  select user_id, max(date) as date
  from logins
  group by user_id
) last_login on last_login.user_id = users.id
left outer join
(
  select user_id, max(date) as date
  from logins
  where isright = 1
  group by user_id
) last_successful_login on last_successful_login.user_id = users.id;
```

This gives you four possibilities per user:

1. The user never tried to login. last_login_successful is null and last_logins_failed is meaningless.
2. The user's logins all failed. last_login_successful is 0 and last_logins_failed is meaningless.
3. The user's last login was successful. last_login_successful is 1 and last_logins_failed is meaningless.
4. The user logged in successfully once, but failed at least th last time they tried. last_login_successful is 0 and last_logins_failed is the number of failures after last successful login.

And here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57b7d/1.

EDIT: To also count failed logins when a user never logged in: If a user never logged in, their last_login.date is null. In last_logins_failed you want to count all records for which the last login occurred *before* OR *never*:

```
  (
    select count(*)
    from logins
    where user_id = students.id and (date > last_successful_login.date
    or last_successful_login.date is null)
  ) as last_logins_failed
```

Comment: This answer definitely deserves more upvotes! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this kind of sql syntax, can you give me a hint how to count the wrong logins even if the user has never logged in correctly? (point 2)

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Please see that I replaced `where last_successful_login.user_id = students.id` with `where user_id = students.id` because last_successful_login.user_id would be null in an outer join situation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like

```
select count(*)
from logins as l join users as u on l.user_id = u.id
where l.timestamp > (select max(timestamp)
                     from logins
                     where user_id = u.id and isright = 1)
```

Get the last timestamp of the login that was successful (subquery) for user
then get a count for all the logins where the timestamp is greater than that of the user, this automatically gives you only the unsuccessful logins because you took the last successful one as a reference timestamp/datetime

Answer (score 0):

How about using a view which only has latest login detail with below query

```
select l.user_id, l.date, l.isright from logins l
where l.date >= (select max(l2.date) from logins l2
    where l2.isright=1 and l2.user_id = l.user_id)
```